# how to focus to textInputLayout after picking order date and delivery date

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

How to focus `textInputLayout` after picking the delivery date.
the result I wanted given below
when the user picks order date and delivery date then automatically goto `orderNo` `textInputLayout`
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y8S9.png)

### actitivity_order.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:hint="@string/orderNoHint"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/orderNo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: why don't you add `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` to the delivery textField? then when return is hit it jumps to the order number.

Comment: @jle that is not possible delivery date is cardView

Comment: Okay might be helpful if you added it to your question to see the relevant code.

Comment: Maybe use view.requestFocus() https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requestFocus(int)

Comment: @qwerty worked but keyboard not appeared automatically

Comment: Check this out: https://captechconsulting.com/blogs/android-request-focus-and-request-focus-from-touch They are using .toggleSoftInput()

Comment: try adding ```requestFocus``` but with a delay.

Answer (score 0):

In My case this was work when i need focus on the any edittext or textinputedittext

`editttext.requestFocus();`

May be in your case you have to use this after picking order date and delivery date

You have to set focus on textinputedittext not on textinputlayout